# trouble figuring out if these functions are bijections or not

Tags: elementary-set-theory

So I am just learning about bijections and I am having difficulty figuring out if these three problems are bijections and how to prove them.

1. $f(x)=x/2$
2. $f(x)=2x^2$
3. $f(x)=\lfloor x\rfloor$

Sorry I forgot to add the entire question. It is "Determine whether each of these functions is a bijection from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R$."

Comment: Presumably they are supposed to be functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$? (The domain and codomain of a function can affect whether or not it is bijective.)

Answer (score 2):

Since you're new to bijections, I'll work out the details of one of them and leave the others for you to try. To show that $f(x) = x/2$ is a bijection, we need to check two things: Whether $f$ is $1-1$, and onto.

- To see if $f$ is $1-1$, we need to see if
  $$f(a) = f(b) \implies a = b$$
  (That is, whether every output has at *most* one corresponding input). This is equivalent to asking whether
  $$\frac a 2 = \frac b 2 \implies a = b$$
  which is certainly true.
- To see if $f$ is onto, we need to see if every real number has a corresponding input. That is, given $b \in \mathbb{R}$, can we find another real number $a$ for which $f(a) = b$? Certainly: Just set $a = 2b$.

Can you try the other two? Hint: Neither is a bijection.

Comment: Ok let me try it out I don't know how to make all the special characters so ill make it as understandable as possible. So for  number 2 you set 2a^2=2b^2 and you divide by 2 to cancel the 2's out, then square root to cancel out the ^2. I am still slightly confused on figuring out exactly how to know if it is onto or not though.

Comment: for the first part a would equal b though.

Comment: @rick The problem is that $a^2 = b^2$ does *not* imply that $a = b$.

Comment: Cant you just use square root and cancel out ^2?

Comment: @rick What happens if you square a negative number?

Comment: this is true...

Answer (score 0):

One way to determine whether f is bijective or not by drawing a figure (if possible). If a line parallel to x cuts f at more than one point, then f is not bijective.